# Marshaller Struct Containing a Field of Type SafeHandle

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I have a P/Invoke function signature to a native function that returns a resource. To avoid memory leaks, I decided to have the P/Invoke function signature return a subclass of `SafeHandle` and let the marshaller do its magic:

```
internal static extern MySafeHandle CreateContext();
```

However, I have another P/Invoke function signature that takes an array of structs, where one field should represent a pointer to the handle created by the above function:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct NativePollerItem {
    internal MySafeHandle Resource;

    internal short RequestedEvents;

    internal short DetectedEvents;
}

internal static extern int Poll(IntPtr pItems, int itemSize)
```

`Marshal.StructureToPtr` throws an exception when I try to use it with this structure: "System.InvalidOperationException -> Structures containing SafeHandle fields are not allowed in this operation"

Because the nature of the `Poll` function is to be called very frequently on the same mutable reference, I wanted to avoid `Marshal.StructureToPtr` anyway, but I can't pin the structure either using `GCHandle` nor can I create a pointer to it in unsafe context to pass either.

The only thing I think I can do is change the definition of `NativePollerItem.Resource` from `NativePollerItem.Resource:MySafeHandle` to `NativePollerItem.Resource:IntPtr`.

That would require me to then call `SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()` which is not recommended for many reasons, but it looks like I don't have a choice.

My question: What is the best, and safest pattern, to use to address the scenario I described here. I am on .NETStandard 2.0 in case there is a difference I am not aware of between it and .NET Framework 4.X. Many thanks!